# Call Azure Function with AD Authorization from a Windows desktop app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, authorization, azure-functions, desktop-application

**GOAL:**
I want to have an Azure Functions (HttpTrigger) that I can call through a Windows desktop app. I want the access to the function be controlled by Active Directory and only authorized users to be able to call it.

**CURRENT STATUS:**
I followed the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-windows-desktop) to create a desktop app, with AD authorization. I also created an Azure Function to which I added an "App Service Authentication" with "Log in with Azure Active Directory" and created a new app registration to handle this. In my desktop app I added a button that calls this function.

**PROBLEM:**
When I call the function directly through its link in a browser, everything works perfectly; if I am authorized, it calls the function, if I am not I am redirected to a log in screen and after a successful log in (for an authorized user only) I get the result of the function.
The problems come when I try to do this through my desktop app. When I press the function call button, I am redirected to the log in screen and as soon as I successfully log in with my credentials, I get the error:

```
AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: <app-id>
```

This happens when in my app registration I do not have an Authentication option for "Mobile and desktop applications", only for "Web".
If I add the "Mobile and desktop applications" option, then the original button (from the tutorial above) can log in and work properly (in the previous case, it is giving me the same error) but this time, when I try to call the function through the button I added, the program is crashing with the errors:

```
Inner Exception 1:
HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.

Inner Exception 2:
WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Inner Exception 3:
IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Inner Exception 4:
SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

If I force the use of TLS 1.2 I get an 401 error: "You do not have permission to view this directory or page.". If I try to call a function that does not use AD authorization, then the whole process is successful. My code:

```
        private async void CallFunctionButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
            var app = App.PublicClientApp;
            ResultText.Text = string.Empty;
            TokenInfoText.Text = string.Empty;

            var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
            var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

            try
            {
                authResult = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, firstAccount)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

                try
                {
                    authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                        .WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                        .WithParentActivityOrWindow(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle)
                        .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                        .ExecuteAsync();
                }
                catch (MsalException msalex)
                {
                    ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}";
                return;
            }

            if (authResult != null)
            {
                this.SignOutButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                string token = authResult.AccessToken;

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    // With an explicit selection of the security protocol the program does not crash.
                    // Instead it gives 401 Unauthorized error, when already signed in.
                    // Without the following line, the program crashes.
                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;


                    string requestUrl = $"the_URL_of_my_function";

                    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
                    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

                    HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
                    var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    ResultText.Text = responseString;
                    DisplayBasicTokenInfo(authResult);
                }
            }
        }
```

**QUESTION:**
Can I call/use an Azure Function that needs authorization through a Windows desktop app and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the issue, it may relate to the TLS version. As fae as I knew, at the moment,  [Azure App Service will be created with TLS 1.2 by default](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/new-app-service-apps-deployed-with-tls-1-2-as-default-from-june-30/). But, WPF application uses TLS 1.0 by default. So we cannot call the Azure function. Regarding how to fix it, please refer to the [document](https://kevinchalet.com/2019/04/11/forcing-an-old-net-application-to-support-tls-1-2-without-recompiling-it/)

---

## Update

Regarding how to call the Azure function projected by Azure AD, please refer to the following steps

1. Configure Azure AD for Azure Function
   [image]
2. Create a client application in Azure AD
3. Configure API permissions and get the scope we nedd
   [image]
   [image]
4. code

```
string[] scopes = new string[] 
{"https://testfun08.azurewebsites.net/user_impersonation" };// the scope you copy
 
 private async void CallFunctionButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
      // get token
          AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
            var app = App.PublicClientApp;
            ResultText.Text = string.Empty;
            TokenInfoText.Text = string.Empty;

            var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
            var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

            try
            {
                authResult = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, firstAccount)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

                try
                {
                    authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                        .WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                        .WithParentActivityOrWindow(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle)
                        .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                        .ExecuteAsync();
                }
                catch (MsalException msalex)
                {
                    ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}";
                return;
            }

       //call Azure function
            if (authResult != null)
            {
                this.SignOutButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                string token = authResult.AccessToken;

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    // Without the following line, the program crashes.
                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;


                    string requestUrl = $"the_URL_of_my_function";
                 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);


                    HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
                    var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    ResultText.Text = responseString;
                    DisplayBasicTokenInfo(authResult);
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: I have already tried to force TLS 1.2. It still does not work, though this time I am getting a 401 unauthorized error (while I am passing the token taken from AD).

Comment: @SpyridonNonServiam Could you please tell me if you provide AD access token  when you call Azure function?

Comment: The problem was indeed in the API Permissions and the relevant scopes. Thank you.